# Resize and lower the bitrate of mp4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, x264

I wanted to execute the following command:

```
x264 --level 30 --profile baseline --bitrate 900 --keyint 30 -o test.mp4 video01.mp4 --vf resize:720,480
```

But I get following output(error)

```
raw [error]: raw input requires a resolution.
x264 [error]: could not open input file `video01.mp4' via any method!
```

What I tried:
 - Adding resolution next to input file, but no luck
 - Tried changing `--vf` to `--video-filter resize:`

What I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to resize mp4 file like this? If the first error refers to input file how can i specify the resolution? I need this command working because I need to implement it in bash script and JAVA code afterwards. From the research I made, I might need avisynth, but there is no port for linux, there is?

If you have something better for me please help me.
I'm running on 64bit Ubuntu 11.04, with all required(maybe) libs for ffmpeg and x264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output indicates that the input file is being decoded as RAW instead of using the proper libav, Avisynth, or ffms decoder.  See the [Ubuntu `man` page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/x264.1.html) for more details.  I believe the proper syntax should be:

```
x264 --level 30 --profile baseline --bitrate 900 --keyint 30 --vf resize:720,480 -o test.mp4 video01.mp4
```

If you still run into errors, it's possible your x264 binary is outdated, or wasn't compiled with support for ffms.  From the `man` page linked above:

> Infile can be raw (in which case resolution is required), [...] or Avisynth if compiled with support (no). or libav* formats if compiled with lavf  support  (no)  or  ffms support (yes).

Finally, from [this thread](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=152442) in regards to compiling x264 with ffms support, the latest x264 should be configurable with your package manager to find the ffms library.